# Get value from list item on list click function

Tags: jquery, jsp

I need to get value of every list click function ,but i didnt get below mentioned things use,please help for solve this
Here is my list :

```
<c:forEach items="${cmlist}" var="records1">
            <section>       <ul id="chapterlist">
                            <li id="cs" class="d" value="${records1.levelID}"><a href="#subchaptercontent">${records1.levelName}</a> <c:forEach
                                    items="${records1.ccourseContentmainList}" var="records">
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="cs1" class="d" value="${records.levelID}"><a href="#subchaptercontent">${records.levelName}</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </c:forEach></li>
                        </ul></section>
                    </c:forEach>
```

and my list click function:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#chapterlist li a").on("click", function(){

         level =  $(this).attr('value');
        console.log( level);
    });});
```

Could u please help anyone to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parent()` and `val()` methods in jQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#chapterlist li a").on("click", function(){    
         level =  $(this).parent('li').val();
        console.log( level);
    });
});
```

[***Documentation of parent() method***](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

[***Documentation of val() method***](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: ,very helpfull,i have solved my issue thank you very much Pranav Ram

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("li").bind("click", function (event)
{                                           {
_id=($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Try this this will handle all clicks on List.